# Populate Pandas DataFrame using a dictionary based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I have a DataFrame

```
>> test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 'D': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
    A   B   C   D
0   a   1       
1   b   2       
2   b   3       
3   b   4
```

I also have a dictionary, where `b` in `input_b` signifies that I'm only modifying rows where `row.A = b`.

```
>> input_b = {2: ['Moon', 'Elephant'], 4: ['Sun', 'Mouse']}
```

How do I populate the DataFrame  with values from the dictionary to get

```
    A   B   C       D
0   a   1       
1   b   2   Moon    Elephant
2   b   3       
3   b   4   Sun     Mouse
```

Comment: I understand how to do this by first turning the dictionary into a dataframe and then merge'ing it with the first. However, this gets very slow if the first dataframe (test) is much larger than its portion that I wish to modify.

Comment: I think transforming your dictionary into a dataframe using `pd.from_dict(your_dictionary)` and then merging with `input_b` seems to me like the best solution. I would be surprised if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`

```
test['C'] = test['B'].map(input_b).apply(lambda x: x[0] if type(x)==list else x)
test['D'] = test['B'].map(input_b).apply(lambda x: x[1] if type(x)==list else x)
```

yields

```
   A  B     C         D
0  a  1   NaN       NaN
1  b  2  Moon  Elephant
2  b  3   NaN       NaN
3  b  4   Sun     Mouse
```

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but from what I understand it got the job done:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], 
                     'D': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})


input_b = {2: ['Moon', 'Elephant'], 4: ['Sun', 'Mouse']}


for key, value in input_b.items():
    test.loc[test['B'] == key, ['C', 'D']] = value

print(test)
```

Yields:

```
   A  B     C         D
0  a  1   NaN       NaN
1  b  2  Moon  Elephant
2  b  3   NaN       NaN
3  b  4   Sun     Mouse
```

This will get slower if the dictionary `input_b` gets too large (too many rows are being updated, too many iterations in the for loop), but should be relatively fast with small `input_b`'s even with large `test` dataframes.

This answer also assumes the keys in the `input_b` dictionary refer to the values of the `B` column in the original dataframe, and will add repeated values in the `C` and `D` columns for repeated values in the `B` column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `update`

```
test=test.set_index('B')
test.update(pd.DataFrame(input_b,index=['C','D']).T)
test=test.reset_index()
test
   B  A     C         D
0  1  a   NaN       NaN
1  2  b  Moon  Elephant
2  3  b   NaN       NaN
3  4  b   Sun     Mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing after setting your index to `B`:

```
test = test.set_index('B')
test.loc[input_b, ['C', 'D']] = list(input_b.values())
test = test.reset_index()

print(test)

   B  A     C         D
0  1  a   NaN       NaN
1  2  b  Moon  Elephant
2  3  b   NaN       NaN
3  4  b   Sun     Mouse
```